# Chord Diagram (D3) with negative values

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization, data-visualization, chord-diagram

I am looking for a way to visualize negative numbers within a chord diagram.

When I add a negative number to my dataset, the group will just expand to the negative side, overlapping the other groups.

Is it possible to add negative numbers to a chord diagram without screwing up the layout?